# Something strange with SQL Server grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a question about what is happening with `group by`.

For example:

```
select COUNT(*)
from 
    (select 0 c1) t1
where 0 = 1
group by t1.c1
```

Result - no records

```
select COUNT(*)
from  
    (select 0 c1) t1
where 0 = 1
--group by t1.c1
```

Result - 0

Why?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns one row.  When all rows are filtered out, then most values on the row are `NULL`.  The exception are `COUNT()` values which are `0`.

An aggregation query with a `GROUP BY` returns one row for each combination of values.  When all rows are filtered out, there are no groups, so nothing is returned.

Your first query has a `GROUP BY` but filters out all rows.  Hence, no rows.  The second query has no `GROUP BY`, so one row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you filter on `WHERE 0 = 1`, no rows will match the filter.

When you also do not add a group by statement, all of the rows from that table will be considered as 1 group. So the result count will be 0 - for the group there are 0 rows that match the filter.

When you add a grouping column, SQL Server must do the same count but now grouped by each distinct value of that column. Since your filter does not return any values for the grouping columns, there are no groups to be made. So the result is no records.

So the difference between the two is 0 groups vs 1 group. No result vs result.